# Using the SELECT operator 'AND' only if a variable is set

Tags: sql, variables, if-statement, operator-keyword

What is the correct/efficient way to display results based on a variable if the variable is set?  If variable is not set, the AND operator should not be used.

I apologize if this is a repeat, I clicked the suggested links and they did not make sense to me.

Near the end of code is my note with ^^^^^ marked.

For example:

```
$whatever = 123;

SELECT  
DISTINCT terms.name as product_type_name,
tax.term_id as termidouter

FROM        $wpdb->posts AS p

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r
ON p.ID = r.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax
ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id

INNER JOIN wp_terms terms
ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id

WHERE
tax.taxonomy = 'product_type'

AND         p.post_status = 'publish'
AND         p.post_type = 'product'
AND         '$whatever ' = terms.term_id
^^^^ If $whatever is empty, I want to return results as if this line did not exist.

ORDER BY product_type_name
");
```

I was going to do an IF/ELSE but I figured that was the lazy way.

```
$whatever = 123;

if (empty($whatever)) {
    // SELECT without the AND
} else {
    // SELECT with the AND
}
```

Comment: AND  ($whatever = terms.term_id OR $whatever IS NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
AND CASE WHEN '$whatever ' IS NOT NULL THEN '$whatever ' ELSE terms.term_id END = terms.term_id
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand this part:  CASE WHEN '$whatever ' IS NOT NULL THEN '$whatever ' but I do not understand the ELSE.  Simply having terms.term_id = terms.term_id sort of causes nothing to happen?

Comment: @LITguy Yep, if '$whatever is not populated, the filter clause becomes  terms.term_id = terms.term_id, which basically is a redundant filter as it will always be true. Your query will return results as if this line did not exist :)

Comment: Marked as the answer. Worked very well and I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: @LITguy Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So... typically you'd want to use prepared statements, but if we're going this route, I would collect all my optional search criteria in an array as strings:

```
$myTerms=array();
if(!empty($whatever)) {
    $myTerms[]="terms.term_id='" . $whatever . "'";
}
...
```

Then you can build your query easily like so:

```
$mySql = "SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE somefield='somevalue' ";
if(count($myTerms)>0) {
    $mySql.=" AND " . implode(" AND ", $myTerms);
}
```

Please note that this is a basic example; you should also be checking any value you pass into your query for attacks etc.

Comment: This is also a great answer.